# Create / Form spacing

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a standard create page. I have added @style = "height: 25" to both label and editor line. My goal is to change the height of the text box, which this does fine, but the label is not aligned in the middle of the text box after I do this?

so my first question is, how do I middle align the label to the text box?

Secondly I want to over all page to not have all the spacing between all the text boxes. Is there a easy way to condense all the spacing?

Thanks,
EB

```
                            @model Intranet.Models.Order

                            @{
                                ViewBag.Title = "CreateOrder";
                                Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
                            }

                            <h2>Create Order</h2>

                            @using (Html.BeginForm())
                            {
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                <div class="form-horizontal">
                                    <hr />
                                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Borrower, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @style = "height: 25px" })
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Borrower, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: 25px" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Borrower, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Officer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Officer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Officer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                   <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }

                            <div>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
                            </div>
```

Comment: Please update your question with rendered code/html to enable us to better help you - perhaps as a snippet with the bootstrap in it via a cdn to reproduce this issue here within your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your custom CSS for it. If you have the default folder structure for the Project, you can write your custom CSS in `Content/Site.css` file.
For your current design default bootstrap css is applied as:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-horizontal .control-label {
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 7px;
  }
}
```

To align the label and set height of textbox globally, Add the below code to `Site.css` file:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .form-horizontal .control-label {
        padding-top: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .form-horizontal .form-control {
        height: 25px;
    }
}
```

See the padding of label was decreased as your current textbox height. You don't need to set height to the label control, it will work fine without it.

Please take a note the you must include `Site.css` file in your `_Layout.cshtml` page if it is not there.

Comment: OK Great. Quick question - my _layout page has @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") so I think I am good there. I added the code to site.css. Do I need to do anything to the view I want this applied to??

Comment: @EbertB, You don't need to add anything else in the view, just remove the inline css that you have applied on the textbox and label using the `@Style` attribute.

Comment: that worked great. 1 other thing - is there anyway to make the Text boxed auto grow depending on the amount of text entered?

Comment: Well, you have to use a Jquery third party plugin with textarea control to achive that. Here is an exmaple of one: (https://github.com/ultimatedelman/autogrow)